# Set LIMIT with doctrine 2?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I trying to write a query (with subquery) but i don't know how set a limit in my subquery.
My query:

```
$query_ids = $this->getEntityManager()
      ->createQuery(
        "SELECT e_.id
        FROM MuzichCoreBundle:Element e_
        WHERE [...]
        GROUP BY e_.id")
     ->setMaxResults(5);

$query_select = "SELECT e
      FROM MuzichCoreBundle:Element e 
      WHERE e.id IN (".$query_ids->getDql().")
      ORDER BY e.created DESC, e.name DESC";

$query = $this->getEntityManager()
      ->createQuery($query_select)
      ->setParameters($params);
```

But **->setMaxResults(5)** doesn't work. No `LIMIT` in the SQL query. Can we do simple LIMIT with doctrine 2 ?

Comment: MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: prove link for 'doctrine does NOT support `limit` in `subqyery`' is : https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/3979  so use native direct sql query !

Answer (score 56):

```
$query_ids = $this->getEntityManager()
      ->createQuery(
        "SELECT e_.id
        FROM MuzichCoreBundle:Element e_
        WHERE [...]
        GROUP BY e_.id")
     ->setMaxResults(5)
     ->setMaxResults($limit) 
    ;
```

HERE in the second query the result of the first query should be passed ..

```
$query_select = "SELECT e
      FROM MuzichCoreBundle:Element e 
      WHERE e.id IN (".$query_ids->getResult().")
      ORDER BY e.created DESC, e.name DESC"
    ;


$query = $this->getEntityManager()
      ->createQuery($query_select)
      ->setParameters($params)
      ->setMaxResults($limit);
    ;

$resultCollection = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: Your response is working, it's what i use in my production code since i ask the question. But in my question i search to set an LIMIT on my first query, for use his DQL in second query. (and do only one database query).

Comment: Is that valid code or pseudo code? When I try that Symfony bugs out with `Notice: Array to string conversion` I can try a custom Hydrator to return a one dimensional array and implode that because there doesn't seem to be one already built that does that: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#hydration-modes

Comment: Be careful if you use JOIN in your DQL. It will not perform as expected: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#first-and-max-result-items-dql-query-only

Answer (score 23):

I use  `Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator` for this, and it works perfectly (doctrine 2.2).

```
$dql = "SELECT p, c FROM BlogPost p JOIN p.comments c";
$query = $entityManager->createQuery($dql)
                       ->setFirstResult(0)
                       ->setMaxResults(10);

$paginator = new Paginator($query, $fetchJoinCollection = true);
```

Comment: The question is how to limit subquery entities, e.g. related entities.

Answer (score 8):

Your **setMaxResults($limit)** needs to be set on the object.

e.g.

```
$query_ids = $this->getEntityManager()
  ->createQuery(
    "SELECT e_.id
    FROM MuzichCoreBundle:Element e_
    WHERE [...]
    GROUP BY e_.id")
;
$query_ids->setMaxResults($limit);
```

Comment: Doesn't work in my case. When i use $query_ids->getDql() the LIMIT is missing.

Comment: Why does this have upvotes? it's exactly the same as the OP but it's just adding more assignments to the same variable

Answer (score 0):

```
$limit=5; // for exemple

$query = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
           '// your request')

->setMaxResults($limit);

 $results = $query->getResult();

// Done
```

Comment: Please do not only post working code, but also a short explanation and summary of your work.

Comment: SORRY it's my first time here to do a post, so for set a limit we must do this function in query 
setMaxResults($limit)
and not forget to define $limit

Comment: @Badrèddine - you can edit your answer to improve it.  SO allows us to correct our mistakes so please take advantage.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$qb = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->createQueryBuilder();  
$qb->select('p')->from('Pandora\UserBundle\Entity\PhoneNumber', 'p');
$qb->where('p.number = :number');
$qb->setMaxResults(1);
$qb->setParameter('number',$postParams['From'] );
$result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read this guide to understand how to write a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer  You should add some context to the code and explain how/why this works.