# Symfony2 - Doctrine : setMaxResults() doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have one problem with doctrine and a custom query in my repository. I work on a website including premium account.
With these accounts you can get not limit with the list member result for example. If you don't have the premium account, the result list is limited to 10 results.

So this is my custom Query :

```
/**
 * Avec cette fonction on obtient la liste de tous les membres
 * en utilisant une pagination
 * @param int $page
 * @param $limitResultPremium
 * @return Paginator
 */
public function getAllUser($page = 1,$maxResultPerPage = 6,$limitResultPremium = 10) {

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u')
        ->where('u.enabled = true')
        ->andWhere('u.dCreated <= '. "'".date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time())."'")
        ->orderBy('u.dCreated')
        ->setMaxResults($limitResultPremium)
    ;

    $query->setFirstResult(($page-1) * $maxResultPerPage)
        ->setMaxResults($maxResultPerPage);


    return new Paginator($query);
}
```

As you can see, I use paginator to paginate my results page. But I want to use the function `setMaxResults()` and it doesn't work.  I have also the max result corresponding to my query (in my case I get 11 results, and I want to only get 10...)

If someone can help me... Sorry for my english ! Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `$limitResultPremium` supposed to do?

Comment: $limitResultPremium is supposed to passed the value of the limitation if the account is not premium or if it is

Comment: So If the current user has a premium account, you want to display only 10 rows, otherwise you allow pagination and all users to be listed, right? There is no way of figuring out, if the user has premium account or not in this function.

Comment: Yes you are right. I do this verification before calling this function and i put a value inside the $limitPremium variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you ended up with this code whilst trying to add pagination to already working code with the `$limitResultPremium`. Calling `setMaxResults` multiple times will result in only the last call having an effect. What you probably want is something like this:

```php
public function getAllUser($page, $maxResultPerPage, $limitResultPremium) {

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u')
        ->where('u.enabled = true')
        ->andWhere('u.dCreated <= '. "'".date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time())."'")
        ->orderBy('u.dCreated');

    if ($limitResultPremium !== null) {
        $pageMax = $limitResultPremium / $maxResultPerPage;
        $page = $page > $pageMax ? $pageMax : $page;
    }

    $query->setFirstResult(($page-1) * $maxResultPerPage)
        ->setMaxResults($maxResultPerPage);


    return new Paginator($query);
}
```

When the user tries to see a page, that is outside his allowed scope, he will be sent to the last page allowed. You should restrict the page in presentation as well (not showing pages higher then `$pageMax`).

Answer (score 2):

You use the `->setMaxResults` method two times.
I suggest you do it like this:

```
public function getAllUser($page = 1,$maxResultPerPage,$limitResultPremium) {

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u')
        ->where('u.enabled = true')
        ->andWhere('u.dCreated <= '. "'".date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time())."'")
        ->orderBy('u.dCreated');

    if ($limitResultPremium) {
        $maxResultPerPage = 10;
    }

    $query->setFirstResult(($page-1) * $maxResultPerPage)
        ->setMaxResults($maxResultPerPage);

    return new Paginator($query);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I've already tried your solution but i catch an error : Attempted to call an undefined method named "limit" of class "Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder".

Comment: Updated my comment. sry had to look up how to set limit again with doctrine2.

Comment: It's not a problem, don't worry :) $maxResultPerPage doesn't limit the result, it's just put a limit on the number or result per page, and this param doesn't depend on the account premium or not

Comment: according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25487590/4969965) it should limit that way...

Comment: i think my problem is that paginator has already done a limit per page. When i click on the second page it will display me the next user but only between the first and the max result. So i think, i have to find another solution for this limit...

Comment: Paginator works exactly in the way as @Fuujin wrote. I am going through its source code and this should work. Can you tell us exact values of the parameters you call the function with and results you get? (Put these in the question, not comments)

Comment: Question updated. My problem is not with paginator but only with the second limitation.

Answer (score 0):

you won't need limitResultPremium if the max result you will use is 10 , also the pge number must not be defined in the params

```
public function getAllUser($page,$maxResultPerPage = 10) {

$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->select('u')
    ->where('u.enabled = true')
    ->andWhere('u.dCreated <= '. "'".date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time())."'")
    ->orderBy('u.dCreated');



$query->setFirstResult(($page-1) * $maxResultPerPage)
    ->setMaxResults($maxResultPerPage);

return new Paginator($query, true);
```